# Can placeholder be used with ref()

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using c++11 features and just experimented the following code:

```
void dump(ostream &os, const MyType &mt)
{

}

void f(const vector<MyType> &mts, ostream &os)
{
   for_each(mts.begin(), mts.end(), bind(dump, ref(os), ref(_1));
}
```

This code compiles wrong at clang:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:2: error: no matching function for call to object of type
      'std::_Bind<void (*(std::reference_wrapper<std::basic_ostream<char> >, std::reference_wrapper<const std::_Placeholder<1> >))(std::basic_ostream<char>
      &, const MyType &)>'
        __f(*__first);
```

If I strip `ref` from `_1`, it compile fine:

```
for_each(mts.begin(), mts.end(), bind(dump, ref(os), _1);
```

Seems like placeholder does not go with reference, but just like to confirm, can you list the semantic definition why it does not? Is it actually already passed by reference?

Comment: your original code makes no sense

Comment: in my experience, either something is so simple that `bind` is not relevant (the case here), or it's so complex that making `bind` work would be just too much work. use a range based loop, just call the function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: And don't forget the lambdas: `for_each(mts.begin(), mts.end(), [&os](const MyType &x) { dump(os, x); });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::ref()` is used to pass values by reference that would otherwise be passed as copies.

In your code, it is used to pass `os`, a local name that obviously you don't want to copy.

Remember that it is the call to `std::bind()` that does the copy. That is, the value returned by `std::bind()` holds a copy of every passed object. `std::ref()` prevents that copy and keeps a reference instead.

But placeholders are not actually values inside the object returned by `std::bind()`. Instead, they are a mark that instruct the function to forward the n-th argument to the wrapped function. The key word here is *forward*: since the value is forwarded, it will be passed as reference if your function takes a reference, and as a copy if your function takes a copy.

Since the `_1` is not the real value to be passed to the function, but instead a library trick to signal from where that value should be taken, using `std::ref()` with it makes no sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, It looks to me that the OP is worried about whether the `mt` argument to `dump()` is a reference to the objects from the container, or if they may be hidden copies. The use of `ref(_1)` would be to avoid such copies. My answer tries to say that there is no hidden copies of the _placeholdered_ object.

Comment: Re "Since the _1 is not a real value", the wording could be improved, because these placeholders are not a core language feature: they're a library solution, and as such very real. It's just that `bind` treats the corresponding types specially. Tucked inside the result of `std::ref` it's not seen by that machinery.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Of course `_1` is a value. Just it is not the value passed to `dump()`, that's what I meant with the word _real_. I've reworded the description, hoping it is clearer now.